Problemas a la hora de hacer un insert dentro de una tabla en Visual Basic
Este es el código que tengo ahora. No sé si le falta algo.
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardarBoleta.Click
    Dim boleta As String = txtBoleta.Text
    Dim nombre As String = txtNombre.Text
    Dim nombreH As String = txtNombreH.Text
    Dim modelo As String = txtModeloH.Text
    Dim cedulaE As String = txtEncargado.Text
    Dim serie As String = txtSerial.Text
    Dim motivo As String = txtMotivo.Text
    Dim estado As String = cmbEstado.Text
    Dim creadoPor As String = txtCreadoPor.Text

    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO boletaNueva (serie, motivo, estado, creadoPor, nombre) VALUES (@serie, @motivo, @estado, @creadoPor, @nombre)"
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serie", serie)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motivo", motivo)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", estado)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creadoPor", creadoPor)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show("Datos guardados correctamente.")
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using

End Sub


Bienvenido. Es importante que el título dé una idea de qué trata tu pregunta en pocas palabras . El cuerpo de la pregunta es donde puedes explayarte. Por cierto eso no es C#, es Visual Basic

¿Lanza la excepción? si es así, que dice?

ES importante mostrar el mensaje de error.

es que a lo que entiendo y se yo en mi BD yo puse las respectivas FK para traer los datos de las otras tablas pero cuando lleno los espacios y le doy al boton guardar me un error de syntasix
